# correct wire and conduit to extend a 30 amp circuit 350 feet

Tags: electrical, subpanel, conduit

I'd like to ask a question here before contacting an electrician.  I plan to install a 30 amp RV connection in a wet environment approximately 350 feet away from a 200 amp distribution panel. Based on voltage drop concerns, I planned to use #6 THWN in 2 inch conduit. I should have 3 90 sweeps in the conduit run. I plan to do most of the dirt and conduit work myself. Is this the right approach, am I missing something or overthinking it?

Comment: Not sure how you ended up posting the question twice, but one should be closed in favor of the other.